# VB function won't go into a loop (Excel)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on an Excel project where I need to import monthly .csv files, parse a column in these and return numbers from adjacent columns back into a summary sheet. Here's the idea:

1. read column to parse into a VB array
2. concatenate string to search for, place it into a variable
3. search for this variable in array
4. if found, write `1` into a second array (named `arrTrueFalse`)
5. if not found write `0` into `arrTrueFalse`
6. when done, multiply true/false array with a third array (range from .csv with amounts) basically do a `SUMPRODUCT` on them

Here is the code, I'll try to mark where it breaks

```
Private strBaba As String
Private arrCampaigns() As Variant
Private arrAmounts() As Variant
Private arrTrueFalse() As Variant

Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0)) 
End Function

Public Sub stringComparison()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    j = 1

    Call OptimizeCode_Begin

    With Sheet14
        arrCampaigns = .Range("F2:F1000").Value
        arrAmounts = .Range("I2:I1000").Value
    End With

    ReDim arrTrueFalse(1 To UBound(arrCampaigns) - LBound(arrCampaigns) + 1, 1 To 1)

    For i = 2 To Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        strBaba = Sheet2.Range("A" & i).Value & "*" & Sheet2.Range("C" & i).Value & "*"

        Call IsInArray(strBaba, arrCampaigns)

        '=> Works up to this line (where I call IsInArray); after that, loop never gets executed?

        If IsInArray(strBaba, arrCampaigns) = True Then
            arrTrueFalse(j) = 1
        Else
            arrTrueFalse(j) = 0
        End If

        j = j + 1
    Next i

    Call OptimizeCode_End
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: for what reason is there `Call IsInArray(strBaba, arrCampaigns)`??? Also `Application.Match` does not work for 2D Arrays :(

Comment: @DirkReichel It does if the second dimension is 1 to 1.

Comment: @DirkReichel: I have to call the function to do it's thing, no?

Comment: @AlexStarbuck You call it twice in a row, discarding the result first time.

Comment: You dont need the call before hand as its a boolean return, as in you use it, like the next line.

Comment: still... why doesn't `arrTrueFalse(j) =...` pop any errors for you? I need to use it like this: `arrTrueFalse(j, 1) =...` or I get the "Subscript out of range" Error...

Comment: @DirkReichel Actually it is :), thanks for pointing it out (although I don't understand why is this so). Now it works, the values in this TrueFalse array do get set but I have another error `ELSE arrTrueFalse(j, i) = 0`. This j gets set to 1000?

Comment: if `j` adds up 1 each loop like `i` why not directly `arrTrueFalse(i - 1, 1)`? (-1 cus i starts at 2 and j at 1)